# React-Flow : Type checking props across React components doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Has anyone got into this problem lately ?

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1279

I'm on flow 0.5 and my code is similar to that issue except that I'm passing type Props as generics to the component:

```
type Prop = {
   key1: string
}
class MyComponent extends React.Component<void, Props, void> {...}
```

Calling : `<MyComponent unknownKey="should fail" />` should fail since unknownKey doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out my problem. My components have an index.js file for exporting and that file needs to be annotated with flow (// @flow).